# Is there a possibility to simultaneously show the tooltips for all the data points in the series on hover of one any points?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there an option to setup Highcharts.js to show the tooltips for all the data points in the series on hover of any of the data point in that series?

E.g. something like this when green bar is hovered over:
[image: example]

I've found many solutions and managed to reproduce for showing multiple series on the same point, but nothing like this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is quite an unusual requirement, so I rather doubt you will find this as an already built-in option. (I can't spot anything, by having a quick look over the documentation.) You will probably have to develop that functionality yourself somehow. I'd start by checking what events (if any) the library emits for when such a tooltip gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for such tooltips, but you can relatively easily create it. It is enough to use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class, add custom labels and show/hide them on `mouseOver` / `mouseOut` series events. The default tooltip uses really similar approach under the hood.

For example:

```
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          const chart = this.chart;
          const points = this.points;

          points.forEach(point => {
            let customTooltip = point.customTooltip;
            const text = `<span style="color:${this.color}">●</span> <span style="font-size: 0.8em">${this.name}</span><br/>x: ${point.x}, y: ${point.y}`;

            const anchorX = point.tooltipPos[0] + chart.plotLeft;
            const anchorY = point.tooltipPos[1] + chart.plotTop;

            if (!customTooltip) {
              customTooltip = point.customTooltip = chart.renderer
                .label(text, anchorX, anchorY - 100, 'callout')
                .attr({
                  align: 'center',
                  zIndex: 8,
                  stroke: point.color,
                  fill: 'rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.75)',
                  padding: 8,
                  r: 5
                }).add();
            } else {
              customTooltip.show();
            }

            customTooltip.attr({
              anchorX,
              anchorY,
              x: anchorX,
              y: anchorY - customTooltip.height - 8
            });
          });
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          this.points.forEach(point => {
            point.customTooltip.hide();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h6ys735b/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label